# Superuser nologin roles?

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions, superuser

In searching for examples of `ALTER` and `GRANT` commands I notice there are times where `superuser` is granted, but `login` is not.

Moreover, it turns out that if you `GRANT SELECT` privileges to a role but *not* `LOGIN`, they can't execute select queries anyway as it depends on login.

So what would be the use for a *nologin* *superuser*, or indeed a *nologin* role full stop? Is the only reason when the role is used as a group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things a role can do even if it cannot login:

- It can own objects.
- It can have other roles as members, that is, it can act as a user group.

As far as I can tell, a superuser owner only makes a difference with functions that are declared `SECURITY DEFINER`. Such functions run in the context of the functions's owner, that is, with superuser privileges. Powerful, but dangerous.

Being a member of a superuser role allows you to assume superuser privileges temporarily by issuing

```
SET ROLE the_su_role;
```

You can return to be a mortal user with

```
RESET ROLE;
```

That can be useful if you want to be able to issue superuser commands, but don't want to expose yourself to the risk of using a superuser all the time, similar to the `su` and `sudo` commands on UNIX.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. And owning objects would be of no use at all if a role could not also act as a group, right?

Comment: It might be precisely be the use case that the object owner cannot log in (and hence cannot `ALTER` or `DROP` the objects). But for that it makes no difference if it is a superuser or not.